# EDT and other Thread relations regard repaint() method java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

if the GUI was sure build by EDT does a repaint call on some other Thread invoke painting on the EDT? if not, how do i make sure it does, the more efficient the better.

Comment: Yes; see [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically method `repaint()` invoke EDT by default, everything works until first `Thread.sleep(int)` was called, then you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html),

Have to look at [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which providing basic funkcionalities for [painting in the Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) or delaying any event(s) in the Swing GUI ,

If your update(s) isn't about [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) then you can invoke EDT by wrapping output to the Swing GUI to the `invokeLater()`