# GUI stuck if for loop is done inside EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I Have this code:

```
Thread T=new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for (int i=0;i<18;i++){
                    int percent=(int)(((i+1)*100)/18);
                    try {
                        lblNewLabel.setText("Loading... ("+percent+"%)");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

my problem is that my label won't change it's text after this thread is stared, but will stay with the old text (before this code label was creted with "Loading...(0%)" text).
is there a way to avoid so?

And then... If i call invokeLater only on my setText call like this:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            lblNewLabel.setText("Loading...("+percent+"%)");
        }
    });
```

it will be called 18 times. is this a good approach? or it is better to don't call so many times the invokeLater method?

Thank you

Comment: It seems like you have used the `edt` tag for "Event Dispatch Thread" but that is not actually what it's for. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/edt/info). I edited to remove it from this question (will be visible after review).

Comment: pardon, didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
    public class UIThreadTest {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel labelStatus;
    private JButton buttonProcess;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final UIThreadTest ui = new UIThreadTest();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ui.initGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("View");
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        labelStatus = new JLabel("Status...");
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(labelStatus, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        buttonProcess = new JButton("Start");
        buttonProcess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Runnable startLoop = new StartLoop();
                Thread startLoopThread = new Thread(startLoop);
                startLoopThread.start();
            }

        });
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(buttonProcess, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void updateStatus(final int val) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                labelStatus.setText("Loading... (" + val + "%)");
            }
        });

    }

    private void runForLoop() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            int percent = (int) (((i + 1) * 100) / 18);
            updateStatus(percent);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class StartLoop implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runForLoop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help, i was near this solution too.. however.. Is it a good idea to call so many times invokeLater? will this be inefficient? or it is a good idea to do this way? in this code it is called 18 times...

Comment: I think it would be as good as calling any other method 18 times. invokeLater documentation says: "Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed." Why do you think it might be inefficient." Also we are not blocking the EDT. You may also like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289331/edt-and-other-thread-relations-regard-repaint-method-java)